# Convex hull of $k$ point is the intersection of $k$ half spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, geometry, convex-hulls

Assume we have $d+1$ vertices in $\mathbb{R}^d$. (We may assume they are affinely independent if necessary.)
[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2130746/convex-sets-as-intersection-of-half-spaces) shows that the convex hull $C$ of these $d+1$ vertices is equal to the intersection of all half-spaces containing them. I am wondering is it true that $C$ is the intersection of $d+1$ half-spaces.

If those vertices are affinely independent, then we can linearly transform the convex hull to a standard $d$-simplex, which is determined by $d+1$ many dimension $d-1$ faces?

And it seems "affinely independence" is necessary?

Comment: If for example you points are all on a line (and d is at least 3) the convex hull is not the intersection of $d+1$ half spaces so you do need some independence condition.

Comment: An ordinary octohedron has 6 vertices and 8 faces.

Answer (score 1):

While passing between vertices and half-spaces is easy in the affinely independent case, it get a lot more complicated in general.

For $d+1$ affinely independent points in a $d$-dimensional real affine space, there is one half-space for every vertex: the $d$ other vertices define an affine hyperplane, and the vertex itself chooses one of the two half-spaces separated by that hyperplane.

However if in $3$-dimensional space one glues together two regular tetrahedra along one triangle, the result is a convex polytope that is clearly the convex hull of its $5$ vertices, but which has $6$ faces so it also clearly needs at least $6$ half-spaces to define it as their intersection. If you embed this in a $4$-dimensional space (so the polytope has lower dimension than the space) then you need two more half-spaces in the intersection to cut out the embedded $3$-dimensional subspace (but the polytope is still the convex hull of $5$ points).

Also the ordinary cube shows that is it possible to have fewer half-spaces than vertices.